# How to set route path by default?

Tags: angular

There are two routes in `AppRoutingModule`:

```
{ path: "list", component: ListComponent },
{ path: "drops", component: DropsComponent }
```

How to set one of them by default if user comes to root URL: `http://local` instead concrete path  `http://local/list` or  `http://local/drops`

Comment: Wow @R.Richards ... that is cool! Is that something new? I'm normally very anti-down voting ... but with this it at least makes it clear why.

Comment: @DeborahK I think that site has been around for a couple of years. It is a good tool for making down vote reasons clear. Down votes serve a purpose. Down votes with a complete explanation make them less frustrating for the receiver.

Comment: Before you folks consider spreading links to that site, I would advise you to read [the community's consensus on that first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355950/1233251).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `''` with `redirectTo`, pay attention to `pathMatch:full`

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: "list", component: ListComponent },
{ path: "drops", component: DropsComponent }
```